# Is it Possible to use schtasks on Python Code?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, windows-task-scheduler

I have set up a windows server on AWS and have set it up to run python. I'm trying to get this to run on a regular basis but I'm not sure is schtasks will work to run the python code. Could you give some advice around this please.

Also, the reason I didn't set this up on a native python friendly OS is because I was having some issues installing the libraries I needed.

Any help or advice is hugely appreciated.

Comment: What reason do you have to think scheduled tasks would not work with Python code?

Comment: I just have not seen any example of how to do it, I'm sorry I'm not a strong programmer at all, how would you allow it so the code is ran, but using the python environment? I know the basic layout is schtasks /create /tn "Task Name" /tr TaskRun /sc... but at what point do I call for python to run the test.py code. I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'schtasks' is just an executable. You can always launch that within python script, using subprocess for example. You need to keep in mind for the following though:

1. It could require elevation. If your script is within ordinary process, you could get UAC prompt, and will need a way to deal with it.
2. If you'd like to create a task running without user logging on, you need to manage user/password.
3. If you create a bunch of tasks, you need to manage them, query/pause/stop/delete???

That's all I can think of right now...